# How do you listen for a HTML element moving in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have an HTML element that I need to track another element. Specifically, I need to have the top left and top right corners of both elements be positioned the same. When a window gets resized, the resize event gets triggered and I can adjust the position of the dependent element. However, if the element being tracked is repositioned (but not resized), I do not see any DOM event.

How can we find out if a DOM element has been moved? We are using the latest jQuery.

Here is a code sample.

Note that `elementOne` and `mouseTracking` divs are there to show elements that get moved for "some" reason that is outside the control of my code.

1. This code works for the `elementOne` case.
2. `MouseTrackingTracker` does not track a moving element.
3. `ResizerTracker` does not put the border around the complete text in the overflow case.

I would like the trackingDivs to move and resize no matter the reason for the tracked element's reasons for changing.

This code relies on the window resize being the hooked event. Hooking some event that fires when the element changes its dimensions is closer to what I need.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
#elementOne { float : right;width : 200px; display:inline-block}
#resizer { float : left; display:inline-block}
.trackedDiv { width:50px; height:50px; background-color: blue }
.trackingDiv { position:absolute; z-index: 1; border:3px green; border-style: solid;}
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
      $( window ).bind("resize",function(){
          $("#elementOne").trigger("reposition");
          $("#mouseTracking").trigger("reposition");
          $("#resizer").trigger("reposition");
       });

       var repositionFunction = function(selfish, element){
           var self = $(selfish);
           var offset = self.offset();
           var selfTop = offset.top;
           var selfLeft = offset.left;

           var selfWidth = self.width();
           var selfHeight = self.height();
           $(element).css({
              top: selfTop,
              left: selfLeft,
              width : selfWidth,
              height : selfHeight
           });
       }
       $(document).mousemove(function(ev){
           $("#mouseTracking").position({
             my: "left bottom",
             of: ev,
             offset: "3 -3",
             collision: "fit"
           });
         });

       var timedShort = function() {
           $('#resizer').html("Really short").resize();
           setTimeout(timedLong, 10000);
       }
       var timedLong = function() {
           $('#resizer').html("Really longggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg text").resize();
           setTimeout(timedShort, 10000);
       }
       setTimeout(timedLong, 10000);

       $("#elementOne").bind("reposition",
               function() { repositionFunction(this, "#elementOneTracker"); });
       $("#mouseTracking").bind("reposition",
               function() { repositionFunction(this, "#mouseTrackingTracker"); });
       $("#resizer").bind("reposition",
               function() { repositionFunction(this, "#resizerTracker"); });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="trackedDiv" id="mouseTracking">tracks mouse</div>
  <div class="trackingDiv" id="mouseTrackingTracker"></div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="trackedDiv" id="resizer">resizer: resizes</div>
  <div class="trackingDiv" id="resizerTracker"></div>
  <div class="trackedDiv" id="elementOne">elementOne: floats to the right</div>
  <div class="trackingDiv" id="elementOneTracker"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? How is element repositioned etc. ?

Comment: example added. I hope this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know when an DOM element moves or is resized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444719/how-to-know-when-an-dom-element-moves-or-is-resized)

Answer (score 4):

You can fire custom events with jquery whenever you reposition the element.

```
$( window ).bind("resize",function(){

   $("#elementOne").css({
      top: 200,
      left: 200
   }).trigger("reposition");

});

// and now you can listen to a "reposition event"

$("#elementOne").bind("reposition",function(){

   var self = $(this);
   $("#elementTwo").css({
      top: self.css("top"),
      left: self.css("left")
   });

});
```

So you can provide event hooks yourself with some manual coding, which is useful since cool events like DOMAttrModified and so on, are not fully supported in all browsers. The downside, you have to do it all yourself.

Comment: I am not repositioning the element I am tracking. I tried out your solution and unfortunately it does not work for my use cases. See update to original question.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there are no reliable events to tell you when an element moves or is resized.  You could resort to *polling* the element, though that won't necessarily be the most performant solution:

```
setInterval(repositionElement, 10);
```

Another option is to make your element "track" the other element purely through CSS.  For this to work, you'll need a "wrapper" around the element you're tracking, and the other element:

```
#wrapper-around-element-to-track
{
    position: relative;
} 

#tracked-element
{
    position: absolute;
    /* set top and left to position, if necessary */
}

#tracking-element
{
    position: absolute;
    /* set top and left to position, if necessary */
}
```

Since you're already using jQuery, you can also use the [resize event plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ba-jquery-resize-plugin) to simulate the resize event on any element, but if I recall the last time I looked at it, it simply does the polling like I mentioned.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to handle the text that flows outside of the element ( resizer when "really long text is displayed" ). The resizer dimensions don't include the overflowed text. However, I do need to figure out a way to include that overflowed text in my border and to correctly handle mouse clicks on the overflowed portion of the text.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [DOMAttrModified](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMAttrModified) event, but its only impleneted in [Firefox and Chrome](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html). But as you need a JavaScript function to start the element moving, you can firing a [custom event with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399867/custom-events-in-jquery) in this place.

Comment: and the documentation lists DOMAttrModified events as deprecated :-(