# jQuery: binding an element to another element

Tags: jquery

I have found this jfiddle (not mine) that represents something similar to what I want to do, which binds an element to the cursor, but is there a way I can bind this element to another element (that moves) instead of the cursor? http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/

Comment: Can you show an example how do you move your element ?

Answer (score 0):

Not without making one yourself from scratch... i think.

I used to have to deal with this problem in actionscript and JS... there usually isn't an event for element move, which is what would be analagous to mousemove in the fiddle you provided.

[How to know when an DOM element moves or is resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444719/how-to-know-when-an-dom-element-moves-or-is-resized)

HOWEVER, you can often get away with binding to another type of event and then animating your block along with that, plus animate the other thing to be in sync with that... which would give off the effect. An example of this is doing animations on window resize events.