# How can I obtain div element's width on load, and when it's resized?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now, I have 100% is square which is defined as `div.newsticker`
I'd like to obtain this width on load, or when it's resized.

How can I do it with javascript?

```
div.newsticker{
    border:1px solid #666666;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
}

.newsticker p{
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it like this in jQuery.

`On Load`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("div.newsticker").width()
});
```

`On Resize`

```
jQuery(window).on("resize", function() {
   var width = jQuery(".newticker").width();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using jQuery, you just use the [`width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) function:

```
// On load (use `ready` or whatever other load event you think appropriate)
$(doSomethingWithWidth);                    // Called on DOM ready
// and/or
$(window).on("load", doSomethingWithWidth); // Called on window load (very late)

// To get resize notification
$(window).on("resize", doSomethingWithWidth);

// And the function
function doSomethingWithWidth() {
    var width = $(".newticker").width();
    // ...
}
```

You might also look at [`innerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/) and [`outerWidth`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/).

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.width()`, `.innerWidth()` or `.outerWidth()`.

`.outerWidth(true)` - full width (with margins, padding, borders)

```
$("element").width();
```

Call it on resize:

```
$(window).on("resize",function(){
    // DO SOME STUFF
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To get on load:

```
var w = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  w = document.getElementsByClass("newsticker")[0].width;
}
```

To get on changing dimendions of the window

```
window.onresize = function() {
  w = document.getElementsByClass("newsticker")[0].width;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two answers that will help you:

This tells you how to get the width. I would run this in a jQuery `$(document).ready(function () {` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/294273/2402338

Others have posted how to get the dimension of the element on window resize, but I am not sure if that is the correct context in which you need to get the resize. If not, this Q/A might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3444837/2402338